# How do I force highcharts to pay attention to min and max on my secondary axis?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to set a secondary axis with a min/max value, and the primary axis often overwrites the max on the secondary axis.

I know that I could use alignTicks:false, but I don't like the way that makes the ticks look. I also know that I can hide the ticks for one of the axes, but again, I don't like they it looks.

I would like to either force the right side to use min/max and figure out the proper tick intervals, or I'd like to force the left side to have a specific number of ticks.

I need some ideas, here's a jsfiddle with my code and some mock data.

http://jsfiddle.net/2s6kK/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "subtitle": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "xAxis": {
            "type": "datetime",
            "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
                "day": "%b %e"
            }
        },
        "yAxis": [{
            "min": 0,
            "startOnTick": false,
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "color": "#4074C3"
                }
            },
            "title": {
                "text": "Revenue",
                "style": {
                    "color": "#4074C3"
                },
                "margin": 5
            },
            "index": 0
        }, {
            "allowDecimals": false,
            "min": 0,
            "max": 100,
            "maxPadding": 0.2,
            "startOnTick": false,
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "color": "#8DAD36"
                }
            },
            "title": {
                "text": "Win Rate",
                "style": {
                    "color": "#8DAD36"
                },
                "margin": 2
            },
            "opposite": true,
            "index": 1,
//        "alignTicks": false
        }],
        "legend": {
            "enabled": true,
            "align": "center",
            "verticalAlign": "top",
            "x": 0,
            "y": -5,
            "borderWidth": 0
        },
        "series": [{
            "name": "Revenue",
            "type": "line",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [5.4,27,27,27,58,0, 0, 0, 0
            ],"pointStart":1377993600000,"pointInterval":86400000
        }, {
            "name": "Win Rate",
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#8DAD36",
            "yAxis": 1,
            "data": [60,48,48,48,48,60, 0, 0, 0, 0
            ],"pointStart":1377993600000,"pointInterval":86400000
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting your tickInterval to 10 in your y-axis definition:

`"tickInterval": 10`

http://jsfiddle.net/2s6kK/1/

Comment: Good idea! I think this combined with the alignTicks:false and gridLineWidth makes it work the way I want it to, and it doesn't look terrible. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/ag7mh/1/